# Reading 24-bit samples from a .WAV file

Tags: c#, .net, audio, signal-processing, wav

I understand how to read 8-bit, 16-bit & 32-bit samples (PCM & floating-point) from a `.wav` file, since (conveniently) the .Net Framework has an in-built integral type for those exact sizes. But, I don't know how to read (and store) 24-bit (3 byte) samples.

How can I read 24-bit audio? Is there maybe some way I can alter my current method (below) for reading 32-bit audio to solve my problem?

```
private List<float> Read32BitSamples(FileStream stream, int sampleStartIndex, int sampleEndIndex)
{
    var samples = new List<float>();
    var bytes = ReadChannelBytes(stream, Channels.Left, sampleStartIndex, sampleEndIndex); // Reads bytes of a single channel.

    if (audioFormat == WavFormat.PCM)  // audioFormat determines whether to process sample bytes as PCM or floating point.
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length / 4; i++)
        {
            samples.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, i * 4) / 2147483648f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length / 4; i++)
        {
            samples.Add(BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, i * 4));
        }
    }

    return samples;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reading (and storing) 24-bit samples is very simple. Now, as you've rightly said, a 3 byte integral type does not exist within the framework, which means you're left with two choices; either create your own type, or, you can pad your 24-bit samples by inserting an empty byte (`0`) to the start of your sample's byte array therefore making them 32-bit samples (so you can then use an `int` to store/manipulate them).

I will explain and demonstrate how to do the later (which is also in my opinion the more simpler approach).

First we must look at *how* a 24-bit sample would be stored within an `int`,

> ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ MSB ~ ~ 2<sup>nd</sup>MSB ~ ~ 2<sup>nd</sup>LSB ~ ~ LSB ~ ~
>
> 24-bit sample: `11001101 01101001 01011100 00000000`
>
> 32-bit sample: `11001101 01101001 01011100 00101001`

<sup>MSB = Most Significant Byte, LSB = Lest Significant Byte.</sup>

As you can see the LSB of the 24-bit sample is `0`, therefore all you have to is declare a `byte[]` with *`4`* elements, then read the 3 bytes of the sample into the array (starting at element *`1`*) so that your array looks like below (effectively bit shifting by 8 places to the left),

> myArray[0]: `00000000`
>
> myArray[1]: `01011100`
>
> myArray[2]: `01101001`
>
> myArray[3]: `11001101`

Once you have your byte array full you can pass it to [`BitConverter.ToInt32(myArray, 0);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx), you will then need to shift the sample by *`8`* places to the *right* to get the sample in it's proper 24-bit intergal representation (from `-8388608` to `8388608`); then divide by `8388608` to have it as a floating-point value.

So, putting that all together you should end up with something like this,

<sup>Note, I wrote the following code with the intention to be "easy-to-follow", therefore this will *not* be the most performant method, for a faster solution see the code below this one.</sup>

```
private List<float> Read24BitSamples(FileStream stream, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    var samples = new List<float>();
    var bytes = ReadChannelBytes(stream, Channels.Left, startIndex, endIndex);
    var temp = new List<byte>();
    var paddedBytes = new byte[bytes.Length / 3 * 4];
    
    // Right align our samples to 32-bit (effectively bit shifting 8 places to the left).
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 3)
    {
        temp.Add(0);            // LSB
        temp.Add(bytes[i]);     // 2nd LSB
        temp.Add(bytes[i + 1]); // 2nd MSB
        temp.Add(bytes[i + 2]); // MSB
    }

    // BitConverter requires collection to be an array.
    paddedBytes = temp.ToArray();
    temp = null;
    bytes = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < paddedBytes.Length / 4; i++)
    {
        samples.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(paddedBytes, i * 4) / 2147483648f); // Skip the bit shift and just divide, since our sample has been "shited" 8 places to the right we need to divide by 2147483648, not 8388608.
    }

    return samples;
}
```

For a faster<sup>1</sup> implementation you can do the following instead,

```
private List<float> Read24BitSamples(FileStream stream, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    var bytes = ReadChannelBytes(stream, Channels.Left, startIndex, endIndex);
    var samples = new float[bytes.Length / 3];

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 3)
    {
        samples[i / 3] = (bytes[i] << 8 | bytes[i + 1] << 16 | bytes[i + 2] << 24) / 2147483648f;
    }
    
    return samples.ToList();
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> After benchmarking the above code against the previous method, this solution is approximately 450% to 550% faster.

Comment: You should left justify you're data. IOW, put the zeros at the bottom instead of at the top. One reason for doing so is that it will put the sign bit in the right location. As your answer stands now, you will not get a negative number representation.  A second reason is that when the data is left justified, you can use the same scaling factor (1.0/0x80000000) to convert to float regardless of the original bit depth (24 or 32 bit).

Comment: Another thing you should seriously consider is converting the ints to float immediately, thus you change List<dynamic> to List<float> and save yourself from having to deal with different types later.

Comment: @jaket Thanks for pointing that out, I'd forgotten about the sign bit. I know I could calculate the floating point value and save myself from using `dynamic` but for this particular situation the SQ must be preserved as much as possible, so converting to and from floating point will only raise the THD+N more than necessary.

Comment: You can go to and from double without any loss.

Comment: @jaket I know, but I need to perform calculations which would require the whole `double` (or `float`) to store the precise amplitude of the samples which would then result in quantization errors when the samples have to be converted back to their original bit depth.

Comment: Sorry, but you are mistaken.  Performing your calculations in 32 bits is going to introduce a lot more error than performing calculations with 53 bits plus a floating point that you get from a double. And even if there is a quantization error going back to 32 bits, it will be in the lsb which you are going to lop off anyway since you only care about 24 bits. If you're concerned about the distortion, then dither is the way to handle it.

Comment: @jaket Ah yes I see now, sorry I completely misunderstood, thank you for point that out again. I'll just edit my post in a min...

Comment: The max value of a 24-bit signed integer is 8388607, not 8388608.